# Swift 2 - Concatenate string and number?

Tags: swift, concatenation

There must be a For loop that can simplify the below code:

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    self.item01.text = defaults.objectForKey("item01") as? String
    self.item02.text = defaults.objectForKey("item02") as? String
    self.item03.text = defaults.objectForKey("item03") as? String
    //...
    self.item14.text = defaults.objectForKey("item14") as? String
    self.item15.text = defaults.objectForKey("item15") as? String
```

Comment: so you are asking how to put this in a for loop? it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Yes. There is a for loop that can simplify that code.

Comment: What is going on here?  the question and  the code do not match,  are we concatenating, or are we assigning here?

Comment: I think he is looking to increment a variable then concatenate it with the word "item"

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear - what Shades said.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/* Number Incrementing */    
var number = 1

/* Array of Items */
let itemsArray = [item01, item02, item03...]

/* Get User Defaults */
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

for item in itemsArray {

    if number < 10 {
        item.text = defaults.objectForKey("item0\(number)") as? String
    } else {
        item.text = defaults.objectForKey("item\(number)") as? String
    }
    number++
}
```

Comment: ZGski seems to be the closest to what I'm after, although I'd like to do it without the array, if possible? The amount of items could run into the hundreds and there has to be a way of creating the 'itemXX' using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate a number to a string, you have to convert it first:

```
"item"+String(num)
```

You can also use interpolation to create the string with other values inside the literal:

```
"item\(num)"
```

But perhaps here the best approach is to format the string with 0 padding:

```
 String(format: "item%02d", num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to generate the array automatically:

```
var arr = [String]()
for i in 1...1000 {
    arr.append(String(format: "item%02d", i))
}
arr // ["item01", "item02", "item03", ...]
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work with ZG's code above...